# How to change the color of the date value when have passed 2 days in a SharePoint list?

Tags: jquery, date, textcolor, sharepoint-2016

I am trying to change the color of Due Date when it is more than 2 days to become **Red** and if within 2 days **Orange** and less then 2 days to be **Green** .
I have created this DueDateStatus calculated column to calculate the amount of days from the current date to the date that is set by the user in the Due Date.

[image]

[image]

The next step for me is to create a jquery that will be added a script editor with the list in the same site page. Unfortunately, this is part where I am stuck with the code or the script. It is not working as expected.

[image]

```
script type="text/javascript" src="https://..../../.../.../Scripts/Libraries/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // Customize the selector based on your HTML structure and due date column name
      $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Due Date')").each(function() {
         var dueDateCell = $(this);
         var dueDate = new Date(dueDateCell.text());
         var today = new Date();

         // Customize the date comparison logic and styling based on your requirements
         if (dueDate < today) {
            dueDateCell.css('color', 'red');
         } else {
            dueDateCell.css('color', 'green');
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

What I tried so far:

- Created a calculated column and validation rule.
- Tried different script editors.
- I cannot try the same with JSON as this is SharePoint 2016 version, not the cloud based.
  Results I am trying to achieve:
  To change the color of Due Date when it is more than 2 days to become **Red** and if within 2 days **Orange** and less then 2 days to be **Green**.